# ESXi 5.0 GP Exception 13 World 2157

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

1st time with Esxi 5.0, I have read the whitebox hcl and it states my box as compatible (Dell 960 Optiplex), I burnt Esxi install onto a cd and booted off it (without changing anything in bios) I only had a sata ssd connected, a usb flash 4gb (which i would have installed esxi on), It started loading fine and half way through it dumped a purple / pink screen with :

`GP Exception 13 World 2157`

This system have 5GB RAM (2x2GB and 1x1GB), Intel VT is active in bios,

Any suggestions or thoughts ?
Will be grateful for your support
Kind regards

Comment: Joeqwerty and Chopper - I don't want to run ESX and virtualize Windows 7 for home use, It is a test box we have at work - so this  this question relates to "ESX / ESXi Server" which will be used to virtualize "Servers" - The solution was to uncheck "LIMIT CPUID" value in BIOS - Thanks for closing this as per the faq :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception 13 is a [general protection fault](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1020181). Since it occurred during your first startup, you simply might be seeing broken hardware. Run a [memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/download.html) on your system as a quick check. I also would try installing on the SSD instead of the USB flash to rule out possible problems with the USB controller or the flash device.

Comment: Thanks Synection for your input - it was an issue (in my case) caused by the "LIMIT CPUID" value being CHECKED in BIOS. I unchecked it - all is well since then, ESX installed fine and supported everything inside Dell OptiPlex 960. Thanks so Much